# How to optimize NLTK pos_tag operation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, nltk

As the title says i am doing a pos_tag operation to remove all the proper nouns from my list in python but it is taking forever as my laptop is low specs. Here is the code.

final is a list with 7000 single word strings.

```
final2 = []
for x in final :
    tag = pos_tag(final)
    final2 = [word for word,pos in tag if pos != 'NNP']
```

As you can see the current approach is not efficient it is O(n^2)and i am not an expert , can this be done in less time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final2 = []
#for x in final : (turns out this was not doing anything)
tag = pos_tag(final)
final2 = [word for word,pos in tag if pos != 'NNP']
```